# c++: Casting void pointer to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt

I'm implementing(overriding) the index function in a QAbstractItemModel derived class, qt treeview MV, where a cast to pointer looks like:

```cpp
TreeItem* parentItem = static_cast<TreeItem*>(parent.internalPointer());
```

Where internalPointer is `void *QModelIndex::internalPointer() const`

How should I change the code to cast the `void pointer` coming from `parent.internalPointer()` to `std::shard_ptr<TreeItem>`?

---

Comment: Is the `shared_ptr` supposed to assume ownership of the pointer? (i.e. `delete` it automatically) Or not?

Comment: No, it's not supposed to take ownership.

Comment: Then why do you want `shared_ptr`? What's wrong with using a raw pointer?

Comment: sorry, i miss understood what you meant. Yeah, the whole point's to have it take care of that.

Comment: Then a simple `std::shared_ptr<TreeItem> parentItem(static_cast<TreeItem *>(...));` should work.

Comment: That does the trick. But, there are two points I'd like to ask for clarification. first, I fail to understand the syntax, second, I can't deduct the syntax/solution for when the parameter (i.e. `parentItem`) has already been initiated. (p.s. while you're at it pls add this as an answer so that i can mark this as solved.) and thanks

Comment: Posted an answer and added the way of assigning to an existing `shared_ptr`. But I'm not sure what to explain about the syntax. `shared_ptr` is a class, and `SomeClass variable_name(...);` creates an object of a class by calling its constructor.

Comment: Yeah, that should've been obvious, idk how i failed to understand. once again thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say `shared_ptr` is supposed to take ownership of the pointer (`delete` it automatically), you want this:

```
std::shared_ptr<TreeItem> parentItem(static_cast<TreeItem *>(parent.internalPointer()));
```

Or, to assign to an existing `shared_ptr`:

```
parentItem = std::shared_ptr<TreeItem>(static_cast<TreeItem *>(parent.internalPointer()));
```

or

```
parentItem.reset(static_cast<TreeItem *>(parent.internalPointer());
```